# Oracle PL Sql Procedure Beetween To date

Tags: oracle, plsql

> ```
> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
> ORA-06512: at "PREPAID_USER.CREDO_TERMINAL_MONITORING", line 8
> ORA-06512: at line 3
> ```

I get this error when I try to get some info from base with BETWEEN dates. In Total I want to get all the amounts from dd/mm/yyyy 10:00 to dd+1/mm/yyyy 10:00

this is my code

```
create or replace package body CREDO_TERMINAL_MONITORING is

 procedure get_terminal_amounts(v_terminal_name VARCHAR2,
                             v_start_date    VARCHAR2,
                             v_end_date      VARCHAR2,
                             o_cursor        out sys_refcursor) is
begin
open o_cursor for
  select SUM(e.amount / 100) as Amount,
         SUM(d.commission_reseller_amount / 100)
    from documents d
   inner join ext_invoices e
      on e.original_document = d.id
   inner join terminals t
      on d.terminal_id = t.id
   inner join products p
      on p.id = d.requested_product_id
   inner join terminal_groups tg
      on tg.id = t.terminal_group_id
   inner join vw_prod_groups v
      on v.id = p.id
   inner join clients c
      on c.id = d.client
   where t.name = v_terminal_name
     and e.incoming_date BETWEEN
         TO_DATE(v_start_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') AND
         TO_DATE(v_end_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')
     and d.function_code = 865
   order by d.system_time desc;
end CREDO_TERMINAL_MONITORING;
```

Comment: what are the values you are sending?

Comment: '01-11-2018 10:00'

Comment: '02-11-2018 10:00' this are both values in t.name i send just simb001

Comment: Oracle disagrees. The error cause is: "You tried to enter a date value using a specified date format, but you entered a non-numeric character where a numeric character was expected.". Could you copy/paste command you used to run that procedure, preferably SQL*Plus session? Do that by editing the question (i.e. don't post it as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing end procedure statement, package should end with:

```
  end get_terminal_amounts;

end CREDO_TERMINAL_MONITORING;
```

Comment: i have this one alreayd . the problem is not in this .. See Error